# Notification can not shown at a given time

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

Notification can't shown at a given time. I have String format Date ("2014-1-10 17:43:00"). I changed it to calendar and call notification method. But it didn't work. Please , guide me, what is I need? Here is my code.

It is String Format Date and Call method.

```
String dtStart = "2014-1-10 17:43:00 ";
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = null;
    Calendar tdy1= Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dtStart);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tdy1.setTime(d1);
    long startTime = tdy1.getTimeInMillis();
    Log.i("tdy1 milli",startTime+"");

    createScheduleNotificationg(tdy1);
```

This is notification().

```
public void createScheduleNotificationg(Calendar showCalendar){
    int year = showCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = showCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Note: zero based!
    int day = showCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = showCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = showCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = showCalendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    month+=1;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getBaseContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
    int id=(int)System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,timealarm.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, showCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Here is onReceive()

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.papers.ch"));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

         // Create the notification
         Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Visit our homepage", System.currentTimeMillis());
         notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Visit our homepage", "http://www.papers.ch",pendingIntent);

         // Fire the notification
         notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Comment: please check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241439/set-notification-at-specific-time-android

Comment: Why you asking this question again-2, As you have already asked this. There you have accepted the answer also....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039824/notification-android

Comment: @ Robi Kumar Tomar The answer you show is right but it didn't work well in my program.

Comment: @ dipali Will it work well? :)