# Displaying push notification while app is not open

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I'm trying to create notifications for my app that **sends notifications when a certain task is due**. Each task has a deadline time so I want to send a notification for each task when their deadline has passed.

My main class is called `RecyclerViewDemoActivity` and inside the `onCreate()` I have this:

```
public void setNotification()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,NotificationClass.class);
    AlarmManager manager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    // hardcoding the time just for this example
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,1449208683000,pendingIntent); 
}
```

and I have a `NotificationClass` that looks like this:

```
public class NotificationClass extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Intent resultIntent=new Intent(this, RecyclerViewDemoActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,resultIntent,0);
        Notification nBuilder= new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("This task is due!")
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        nBuilder.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(1,nBuilder);

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.grokkingandroid.samplesapp.samples.recyclerviewdemo" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
<application

    android:name="com.teamvallartas.autodue.RecyclerViewDemoApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.teamv.RecyclerViewDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241439/set-notification-at-specific-time-android) resource for the code above and also [Vogella's resource](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html) on notifications but I don't know why this is not working.

Comment: Did you analysed logs.. is onCreate of Service getting called? If not, check if your service has been added into manifest.

Comment: @PankajKumar You're right... it doesn't seem to call it.

Comment: Then check manifest. You need to add service there.

Comment: @PankajKumar I'm guessing adding an activity? But wouldn't that require an XML file to go with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `onCreate` of `Service` class is getting called. If it is, then the problem is "*You placed your code at wrong method.*".

You need to move code into [`onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)).

Like

```
@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Intent resultIntent=new Intent(this, RecyclerViewDemoActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,resultIntent,0);
        Notification nBuilder= new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("This task is due!")
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        nBuilder.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(1,nBuilder);

      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
      return START_STICKY;
  }
```

---

Update your manifest and add this entry to it

```
<service android:name=".NotificationClass" />
```

Comment: So I moved the code to onStartCommand and tried to print something but it doesn't appear in the logs... What am I missing?

Comment: Done. Has it got to do with the intent tag? I removed the other activities for other files that are not relevant, btw.

Comment: '<service android:name=".NotificationClass " />' add this entry to manifest, below activity tag.

Comment: Oh... the space solved it... But it still doesn't print statements inside onStartCommand()... this is not supposed to happen right?

Comment: Well I don't know whether onStartCommand() should be printing any print statements because it isn't, but I did get notifications to appear. Do I need to do anything in the onCreate of the NotificationClass?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in this way ,

**1st >** create one local broadcast receiver ,

- inside **onReceive()** method , put your code stuff for generate notification
  ,that is your **setNotification()** method .

**2nd >** you just register  that broadcast receiver inside **onCreate()** and unregister it inside **onPause()** or **onDestory()** method . like this ...

**ReceiverActivity.java**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
  ...    
  // Register your broadcast receiver here ...      
  // with actions named "custom-event-name"...
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("custom-event-name"));
}

protected void onDestroy() {
  // Unregister your receiver
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onDestroy();
}
//here comes our receiver ...
// Our handler for received Intents. This will be called whenever an Intent
// with an action named "custom-event-name" is broadcasted.
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 //called setNotification() here ...
  }
};
```

Now let suppose you want to generate notification on click event of your button then fire intent like this,

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("custom-event-name");
  // You can also include some extra data.
  intent.putExtra("message", "Its me!!!!");
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

your **setNotification()**should be like this ..

```
public void Notification(Context context, String message) {
        // Set Notification Title
        String strtitle = context.getString(R.string.notificationtitle);
        // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
        // Send data to NotificationView Class
        intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
        intent.putExtra("text", message);
        // Open NotificationView.java Activity
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                // Set Icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosmall)
                // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker(message)
                // Set Title
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notificationtitle))
                // Set Text
                .setContentText(message)
                // Add an Action Button below Notification
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Action Button", pIntent)
                // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
```

Comment: It seems very complicated, I saw a similar tutorial here https://gist.github.com/Antarix/8131277 but I think I'm sticking with the simpler way for now. Thanks for your help!